# Create timestamp sequences in pandas Series starting from another given timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

Assume that I have a data frame called `df`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"user_id": [2124, 18420],
                   "on_pm_at": [pd.Timestamp("2018-06-21 11:06:33.620913"),
                                pd.Timestamp("2018-02-24 04:56:48.175177")]})

+---------+----------------------------+
| user_id |          on_pm_at          |
+---------+----------------------------+
|    2124 | 2018-06-21 11:06:33.620913 |
|   18420 | 2018-02-24 04:56:48.175177 |
+---------+----------------------------+
```

I'd like to create a new data frame (let's say `new_df`) where each users have timestamps of dates of ends of months until the current month. For example, today is July 13, the end of this month is July 31, so:

```
+---------+------------+
| user_id |   months   |
+---------+------------+
|    2124 | 2018-06-30 |
|    2124 | 2018-07-31 |
|   18420 | 2018-02-28 |
|   18420 | 2018-03-31 |
|   18420 | 2018-04-30 |
|   18420 | 2018-05-31 |
|   18420 | 2018-06-30 |
|   18420 | 2018-07-31 |
+---------+------------+
```

My best attempt (but seems ugly) so far is:

```
df.groupby(["user_id", pd.Grouper(key = "on_pm_at", freq = 'M')]).agg({"user_id": "size"}).rename(columns={"user_id": "size"}).reset_index().drop(columns="size")

+---------+------------+
| user_id |  on_pm_at  |
+---------+------------+
|    2124 | 2018-06-30 |
|   18420 | 2018-02-28 |
+---------+------------+
```

It gives me starting points of each user, but I don't know how to proceed. I've seen `datetime.timedelta` but it cannot have deltas of months. Is there any way to get to my expected data frame? It doesn't have to start from my previous attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Month period** solution:

First convert columns [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) of `months` and also get `Period` of `now` and then use [`itertuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) with [`period_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.period_range.html), last for datetimes use [`to_timestamp`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Period.to_timestamp.html):

```
df['a'] = df['on_pm_at'].dt.to_period('m')
now = pd.Period(pd.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m'),freq='m')
print (now)
2018-07

df1 = pd.concat([pd.Series(r.user_id,pd.period_range(r.a, now, freq='m')) 
                 for r in df.itertuples()]).reset_index()
df1.columns = ['months','user_id']
df1['months'] = df1['months'].dt.to_timestamp('m')
print (df1)
      months  user_id
0 2018-06-30     2124
1 2018-07-31     2124
2 2018-02-28    18420
3 2018-03-31    18420
4 2018-04-30    18420
5 2018-05-31    18420
6 2018-06-30    18420
7 2018-07-31    18420
```

**Datetime's solution**:

Similar approach, for last day of month convert to `month period` and then to `timestamp`s and use [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html):

```
df['a'] = df['on_pm_at'].dt.to_period('m').dt.to_timestamp('m')
now = pd.Timestamp(pd.datetime.now()).to_period('m').to_timestamp('m')
2018-07-31 00:00:00

df1 = pd.concat([pd.Series(r.user_id,pd.date_range(r.a, now, freq='m')) 
                 for r in df.itertuples()]).reset_index()
df1.columns = ['months','user_id']
print (df1)
      months  user_id
0 2018-06-30     2124
1 2018-07-31     2124
2 2018-02-28    18420
3 2018-03-31    18420
4 2018-04-30    18420
5 2018-05-31    18420
6 2018-06-30    18420
7 2018-07-31    18420
```

Comment: @unutbu - Thank you for comment, I dont know it.